# Как передать Двумерный массив с помощью Intent?

Tags: android

По нажатию кнопки открывается новое Активи и надо передать ДВУМЕРНЫЙ массив в новое Активити, как реализовать? Если можно с примером (оправки и получения).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться интерфейсом `Serializable` (а массивы его как раз реализуют) [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12214949/3212712):

Записываем:

```
bundle.putSerializable("list", selected_list); // Here bundle is Bundle object.
```

Получаем:

```
String[][] passedString_list = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("list");
```

Пример:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("list", selected_list);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```